# Equivalence of norms (Frobenius and L1)

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I've been trying to prove that the Frobenius and 1 norm are equivalent, satisfying the following inequalities ($A\in \mathbb F^{m\times n}$, with $m\geq n$):
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt m}||A||_1 \leq ||A||_F \leq \sqrt n ||A||_1 $$

While proving the second inequality has been quite straightforward (I have proved that $||A||_F ^2 \leq  n ||A||_1 ^2$, which is equivalent), I haven't been able to figure out the first one. I suppose that I should aim for the inequality $||A||_1 ^2 \leq  m ||A||_F ^2$, but I don't know how to continue.

(The definition of the 1 norm I'm using is $||A||_1 = \max_{j=1,...,n} \sum_{i=1}^m |a_{ij}| $)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\le2(a^2+b^2)$.
More generally, $$\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i|\le \sqrt{m}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i|^2}$$
$$\therefore\ \|A\|_1=\max_j\sum_{i=1}^m |a_{ij}|\le\sqrt{m}\max_j\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{ij}|^2}\le\sqrt{m}\sqrt{\sum_{ij}|a_i|^2}=\sqrt{m}\|A\|_F$$

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, suppose the maximum of $\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{ij}|$ occurs on the first column of $A$, which for convenience we denote by $v$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_1
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|v\|_1
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\langle |v|,\mathbf 1\rangle
\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|v\|_2\|\mathbf 1\|_2
=\|v\|_2\le\|A\|_F.
$$